# How to add custom menu item on plugin activation?

Tags: menus, activation, add-menu-page

When my plugin is activated, I would like to add a new menu item. Here is my code:

```
class My_Plugin {
  function __construct() {
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'install'));
  }

  function install() {
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_menu_item'));
  }

  public function add_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page(...);
  }
}

$my_plugin = new My_Plugin();
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I notice that `install` is called, but `add_menu_item` isn't.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins are activated in a sandbox and their output is captured to check for errors, and redirect if activation was successful. Adding something in an activation hook will cause it to run once in that "invisible" sandbox on activation, and that's it.

When you add an action, you're only adding it *for that request*, if you want your menu item to be visible on every admin page load, the `add_action` should be moved to the `__construct` function.